# Нужно занести символы из файла в символьный массив. После запуска программы срабатывает точка останова, ошибка

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int len(char* ch) {
    int i = 0;
    while (ch[i] != '\0') {
        i+=1;
    }
    return i;
}
int main() {
    
    std::ifstream file("lab.txt");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Файл не открыт!";
    }
    else {
        int n = 0;
        char* str;
        char ch;
        str = new char[n];
        int count1 = 0;
        std::cout << "Stroka:" << std::endl;
        while (!file.eof()) {
            file>>str;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<len(str); i++) {
                std::cout << str[i];
            }
        }
        delete[] str;
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или вы пытаетесь создать массив в динамической памяти с размером 0?

```
int n = 0;
char* str;
...
str = new char[n]
```

Comment: Это же вроде как инициализация переменной, компилятор ошибку выдает, если 0 убрать

Comment: И правильно ругается, потому что иначе вообще неизвестно, какое количество памяти вы просите. А так вы просите *нулевое* количество памяти. Какой длины слова можно читать в память длиной 0? Места даже на матерные не хватит...

Comment: Для объявления переменной достаточно

```char* str;```

Если вам важно инициализировать её (что является хорошим тоном, на самом деле), используйте ```char* str = nullptr;```